# the meaning of a quote about cinema

Tags: quotes

I can't understand the meaning of these statement.

> The need of the hour is to promote good cinema and for this it needs
>   to be incorporated in the academic curriculum.

can anybody help me to know that?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Please include your research.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good or clear writing.

"The need of the hour" is an unnecessarily literary way of saying "What is needed right now".

The antecedent of "it" is presumably "cinema" - or, rather, "cinema studies" - but it's hard to determine that from the words alone.